# MySQL Update Query based on Values

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have two table, Table A and B.

Table A has values as follows

```
ID  NAME
1   text
2   voice
3   internet
```

and Table B has vales as follows

```
ID  Bundle Column3
1   AA  
2   BB
3   CC
4   DD
5   EE
```

Requirement is to update **Column3** of *table B* with the *ID* from table A based on Values of Table A. i.e, "**text**" from table A's ID should be added to Column3 of Table B having values "**AA**" and "**BB**".

How the Query is Written in MySQL and Oracle?

Resultant table should look as follows:

**TABLE B:**

```
ID  Bundle Column3
1   AA      1
2   BB      1
3   CC
4   DD
5   EE
```

Comment: What about the last two records in TABLEB ? Please post your expected result in tabular form

Comment: Can you specify logic to update values of column 3 from Table B?

Comment: @1000111 - Other Values can be neglected

Comment: @Sandesh - Column3 of table B should be updated with the ID from table A based on Values of Table A. Ex: text" from table A's ID should be added to Column3 of Table B having values "AA" and "BB".

Comment: Don't repeat what you said in the question. His question is `WHY`?

Comment: Still not clear. Would you please post how the table would look like after the UPDATE operation?

Comment: I think he may want to update tableb's column3 which its column `Bundle` is **AA**, **BB** with tablea's `NAME` which `ID` is 1.

Comment: @Satish: Do you have fixed criteria for updating column3 value from table B? I mean do you just need to update ID of "text" from Table A to Column3 for rows containing "bundle" column values "AA" & "BB"?

Comment: @sagi - His Question is Not Why, its about Logic (Just FYI)

Comment: @Sandesh - Yes. Exactly

Comment: @1000111 - updated

Comment: Would you please explain how this entry `2   BB      1` appeared in the resultant table?

Comment: @1000111 - "text" id is 1 (of Table A) which is added to "AA" and "BB" of table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full script with test data. It's always recommended to provide test data or give us fiddle link to play with. :)

Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,'text');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (2,'voice');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (3,'internet');

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
ID INT,
Bundle VARCHAR(100),
Column3 INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TableB (ID,Bundle) VALUES (1,   'AA');  
INSERT INTO TableB (ID,Bundle) VALUES (2,   'BB');  
INSERT INTO TableB (ID,Bundle) VALUES (3,   'CC');  
INSERT INTO TableB (ID,Bundle) VALUES (4,   'DD');  
INSERT INTO TableB (ID,Bundle) VALUES (5,   'EE');
```

# Actual Query

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET Column3 =( SELECT 
                    ID
               FROM TableA AS A
               WHERE A.NAME='text'
             )
WHERE Bundle IN ('AA','BB')

;

SELECT * FROM TableB;

# Clear Testing Tables

DROP TABLE TableA;
DROP TABLE TableB;
```

Comment: Thnx. It Works. :) . How to ignore case sensitivity for "text", "AA" and "BB" ?

Comment: By default MySQL does not consider case for strings. It appears to be collation setting applied on database/table./column. You can change collation of field in WHERE clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: Same case with oracle also?